# how to remove indirect left recursion from grammar in ANTLR

Tags: parsing, recursion, grammar, antlr3

I have written following grammar in ANTLR. I am facing left recursion error as there is indirect left recursion in below grammar:

```
logicalExpression
  : subSearchCondition delim (logicalOp delim subSearchCondition delim)* ;

  subSearchCondition
  : (NOT)? delim LPAREN delim searchCondition delim RPAREN delim

  | (NOT)? delim predicate delim;

 searchCondition
  : logicalExpression;
```

In the above grammar logicalExpression is calling subSearchCondition which in turn is calling searchCondition, but searchCondition is making call to logicalExpression thus there is indirect recursion between logicalExpression  and searchCondition .

Please help to solve the left recursion for this grammar. Please explain step by step

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc430/lec4.pdf

Comment: It would be good if you can explain it with example for my specific use case

Comment: Why? Since there are tokens defined in between the recursive call, the ANTLR grammar is not wrong. If you're facing problems, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).